# MongoDB Conditional Pop

Tags: mongodb

I am using `MongoDB version 2.2.2` Assume that I have a user collection that contains the documents below;

```
{name:"name1",devices:[{deviceModel:"XR7",deviceVersion:5},{deviceModel:"ZG7",deviceVersion:3}]}
{name:"name2",devices:[{deviceModel:"XR7",deviceVersion:4},{deviceModel:"GY5",deviceVersion:2}]}
```

I wanna remove element of devices element with `"deviceModel" : "XR7"`. The result should be like;

```
{name:"name1",devices:[{deviceModel:"ZG7",deviceVersion:3}]}
{name:"name2",devices:[{deviceModel:"GY5",deviceVersion:2}]}
```

Querying and selecting one element of an array can be done with aggregation but I don't know how to do that when it is removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your collection is named `dev`, you can try the following:

```
db.dev.update({},{$pull:{devices:{deviceModel:'XR7'}}},{multi:true})
```